# Python multiprocessing and Django - I'm confused

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

I'm trying to write a Web app in Python, which is to consist of two parts:

1. A Django-based user interface, which allows each user to set up certain tasks
2. Worker processes (one per user), which, when started by the user, perform the tasks in the background without freezing the UI.

Since any object I create in a view is not persistent, I have no way of keeping tracks of worker processes. I'm not even sure how to approach this task. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It seems a problem that could be solved with [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/). Each user starts an asynchronous task in Celery and eventually you get the result again in Django.

Celery returns an `AsyncResult` instance that is used to wait for the task to complete or check if it has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can try celery as it's django friendly. 
But if to be honest i'm not fond of it (bugs :)

We are going to switch to **Gearman**.
Writing your own job producers and consumers (workers) are a kind of a fun!